# How to submit iron-form via ajax in Polymer 3

Tags: polymer, web-component, polymer-3.x, iron-ajax, iron-form

### The Problem

I want to submit an iron-form in Polymer 3. I use a paper-button and the form has to be submitted via iron-ajax.

This is my **view.js**

```
import { PolymerElement, html } from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
import './shared-styles.js';

class Foo extends PolymerElement {
    static get template() {
        return html'
            <iron-form>
                <form id="formOne" method="post" action="https://my-api-url.com" is="iron-form">
                    <paper-input name="input-1" placeholder="Input One"></paper-input>
                    <paper-button on-tap="submitHandler">Submit</paper-button>
                </form>
            </iron-form>
        ';
    }

    submitHandler() {
        this.$.formOne.generateRequest();
    }
}
window.customElements.define('foo', Foo);
```

*My form is not submitted when clicking the paper-button.*

### What I tried

- I created a iron-ajax element manually and did a request with
  `generateRequest()`. That worked.
- I put an alert in the `submitHandler` function. It was shown.
- I tried submitting the form with `this.$.formOne.submit()`. That worked, too. Of course the form wasn't submitted via ajax but the api page was opened.
- I created a normal `<button>` to submit the form. This works and also sends the form via ajax, but I want to use the paper-button.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think "submitHandler" Method should be outside of template() block.

Comment: you also haven't imported "paper-button"

Comment: @MitulGedeeya Why should the method be outside the template? The method is successfully called. I imported paper-button (and the other webcomponents) in my main view.

Comment: I think Mitui is referring to the `submitHandler` inside `static get template()`, which is a syntax error. Most likely that's a copy-paste error.

Comment: Ah I see. Yes, that's a copy-paste error. It's inside my class but not inside `static get template`. I edited my question for future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried submitting the form with `this.$.formOne.submit()`. That worked, too. Of course the form wasn't submitted via ajax but the api page was opened.

The issue is you're incorrectly calling [`<form>.submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) (executes the synchronous `submit` method of the native `<form>`) instead of `<iron-form>.submit()`. To resolve the issue, move the ID to the `<iron-form>`, which would execute the intended asynchronous `submit` method:

```
<iron-form id="formOne">
  <!-- <form id="formOne"> --> <!-- DON'T DO THIS -->
  <form>...</form>
</iron-form>
```

[demo](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/pyrite-consonant?path=index.html:21:33)

Comment: Woah! That was it. Thanks.

Comment: @Lukas No problem :)

Comment: While we're at it.. Can you tell me how to use the response data in my html around the form? I tried `let response = this.$.formOne.submit();` but console says "undefined".

Comment: The response is not synchronous, so you can't call a function get the response data. You'll have to add an event handler on `iron-form-response`. Feel free to ask a new question, as others may be able to provide a detailed answer that you might find more helpful.